# In Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord, looking for case-insensitive sorting that actually works

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

ActiveRecord model: How to sort and be case insensitive?

After searching Google and trying a bunch of SO solutions, nothing seems to work and many other solutions are not as elegant as I would expect (they require invoking other methods explicitly rather than just work as a built-in-default, etc.).

This statement is what I like in its simplicity. The problem is that it is case sensitive:

```
default_scope -> { order(alias: :asc) }
```

Here are some solutions that I got from Google and SO:

```
1. default_scope -> { |alias| where(alias: alias.downcase) }
2. scope lambda { |email| where(email: alias.downcase) }
3. default_scope order: 'lower(alias)'
4. default_scope -> { order(lower(alias: :asc)) }
5. default_scope -> { order(lower(:alias) :asc) }
```

None of these solutions work: most generate errors. Perhaps this is because I am on Rails 5.0.2 and these are designed for old versions? I don't know.

In Ruby, at my stage of development, it is the simple things that trip me up. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution here does work. After getting to this point, this is rather obvious but what throws me off is the strange answers that were recalled in the original question that were found by researching this problem that absolutely don't work.

```
default_scope -> { order('lower(alias) asc') }
```

Comment: You should provide more detail than a single line of code. See [answer].

Comment: You are right. Added a little more info but it isn't very insightful because I don't understand why there were so many things that 'didn't' work after doing research.